# not getting a proper sum

Tags: c++, c, for-loop, if-statement

I'm trying to get ready for an exam for my year one programming course. I need my `if` statement to return a sum with the number of characters before the user enters a `'p'` or `'P'` in a 10 character string. However, I can't seem to get it to count properly.

```
for (int i=0;i<=strlen(toProcess);i++){
  if (toProcess[i]!='p'|| toProcess[i]!='P'){
    sum=sum+1;
    printf("%c ", toProcess[i]);
  }
}
```

Comment: Step through your code execution with a debugger and you'll see your logic mistake. See https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/. You will be a lot better off in your exam if you learn how to debug yourself compared to having someone else debug for you.

Comment: It's inefficient to call `strlen` in a loop. maybe some compilers can optimize it out, but it's better to change  `for (int i=0;i<=strlen(toProcess);i++)` to just `for (int i = 0; toProcess[i] != '\0';i++)`

Answer (score 3):

```
if (toProcess[i] != 'p' || toProcess[i] != 'P') {
```

Short of some quantum-mechanical-weird universe where something can be `p` and `P` at the same time, this condition will *always* be true<sup>(a)</sup>:

- if it's neither `p` nor `P`: `true || true -> true`.
- if it's `p`: `false || true -> true`.
- if it's `P`: `true || false -> true`.

You need to use `&&` for this particular case:

- if it's neither `p` nor `P`: `true && true -> true`.
- if it's `p`: `false && true -> false`.
- if it's `P`: `true && false -> false`.

---

And, of course, if you want to *stop* after finding the first `p` or `P`, you need to break out of the loop as well. You could either do that as an `else` block for your (corrected) condition:

```
int sum = 0; // probably needed.
size_t len = strlen(toProcess); // cache for efficiency.
for (int i = 0; i < len); i++) {
    if (toProcess[i] != 'p' && toProcess[i] != 'P') {
        sum++;
        printf("%c ", toProcess[i]);
    } else {
        break;
    }
}
```

Or, you could change the condition to just be an early exit:

```
int sum = 0; // probably needed.
size_t len = strlen(toProcess); // cache for efficiency.
for (int i = 0; i < len); i++) {
    if (toProcess[i] == 'p' || toProcess[i] == 'P')
        break;
    sum++;
    printf("%c ", toProcess[i]);
}
```

You'll notice in *both* those cases, I've also changed `<=` into `<`. A ten-character string has character positions `0..9` so those are generally the indexes you should use. I've also ensured that, for efficiency, we're only calling `strlen()` *once,* on the assumption the string doesn't change while processing.

---

<sup>(a)</sup> Of course, my physicist buddies will tell me that the act of *observing* `toProcess[i]` will cause it to collapse to one or the other, so this isn't *technically* correct. Leave it to physicists to spoil an otherwise funny physics joke :-)

Comment: But I only need it to print up to the first p

Comment: @Igor, see the update for this particular requirement.